# Carbon toTimeString not updating

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I'm doing an update, and am getting the date with Carbon::now();

```
$dt = Carbon::now();                  
'date'          => $dt->toDateString(),
'time'          => $dt->toTimeString(),
```

When I check the database, my date field has the proper date string in place based off of today's date. When I check the time field (a datetime field in MySQL), I just see 0000-00-00 00:00:000 and nothing is updated.

Do I need to change the database field type to something else, or do I need to call something different to get the time out of the Carbon::now(); ?

Comment: Why split the datetime into its constituents when both MySQL and PHP have ways to do that on the fly? This solution may lead to errors in that you could update the date or time only and end up with inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` field is expecting a string like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but the `toTimeString` function returns only the `HH:MM:SS` portion.  When you attempt to insert this into the database, MySQL doesn't know what to do with it so it just sets the field to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Use the function `toDateTimeString()` instead when inserting into a datetime field.

```
'date'          => $dt->toDateString(),
'time'          => $dt->toDateTimeString(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data as a timestamp.

Then perhaps add a date mutator to your model to turn them into carbon instances.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Then when outputting/using the date you can use carbon's string formatting..

```
$this->created_at->toTimeString()  // 14:15:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you put the date and time columns with other **$fillable** inside the model.

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'date_column',
       'time_column',
   ];
}
```